# Store part of file name as variable in Linux Shell

Tags: linux, shell-script

Current File Name: `017251004_2301941_5193716.xml`
Require num: `5193716`

I need to store the number after last `_` and before `.xml` into a variable.
Can someone please provide the syntax for same.

I tried this, `num="${file:19:7}"`
but it works for some extent, as I have 4 million files, so after getting some files, it doesn't get full name.

current code:

```
for file in "$origin"/*.xml
do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue    # In case there are no files to copy
        name=${file%.*}               # Strip extension
        name=${name##*/}              # Strip leading path
        save="${name}_$dt.xml"        # Backup filename with datetime suffix

        num="${file:19:7}"

echo "Copying file from Server A to Server B"
        scp -C -- "$file" "$username@$ip:$destination"
done
```

Comment: I assume you want to have something like this:  `tmp="${file##*_}"; fnum="${tmp%.*}"; echo "$fnum"`.  The temp will for example store: `5193716.xml` and the `fnum` will get rid of the extension and keep only the number.

Comment: User3792741 the techniques for doing so are already in the code you copied. It's even commented. Why don't you take a look and try it yourself? Good learning practice even if you don't succeed - and you can show your attempts in the question too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test wrapper
file="017251004_2301941_5193716.xml"
num=$(basename "$file" ".xml" | cut -d_ -f3)
printf "file=$file,num=$num\n"
exit 0
```

Of course, read `man basename cut`.

Answer (score 0):

You already have code that iterates `$file` across your set of files:

> ```
> name=${file%.*}               # Strip extension
> name=${name##*/}              # Strip leading path
> ```

If you insert a debugging line at this point you will see that `name` contains the file name without the `.xml` extension:

```
echo "# file=$file, name=$name #" >&2
```

For example, `name=017251004_2301941_5193716`. From here it's a simple matter to use the pattern matching tools in `bash` once again to extract the last `_`-separated element:

```
fieldNum=${name##*_}          # Extract last `_`-separated field value
```

I think that it would be worth your while to read the section in `man bash` pertaining to *Parameter Expansion*, particularly the part describing `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` (along with their doubled `##` and `%%` variants). You can experiment directly in the shell - no need for a script - with commands like these and other variations on them

```
f=/path/to/my.file.txt
echo "Strip trailing parts: '${f%/*}' and '${f%.*}' and '${f%%.*}'"
echo "Strip leading parts: '${f#*/}' and '${f##*/}' and '${f##*.}'"
```